# Animación en consola c#

Tags: c#, consola

Tengo una pequeña animación que se mueve hacia la parte izquierda de la pantalla de la consola. Funciona, pero produce un parpadeo

¿Cómo soluciono eso?

Y lo otro, es que quiero que cuando llegue al borde izquierdo de la consola, se vaya borrando de a poco y no con el `Console.clear();` Quiero que de la parte derecha vuelva a aparecer y que se deslice hacia la parte izquierda y así sucesivamente.

Dejo el código:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 60, b = 0;
            GenerarPiso();
            while (true)
            {
                GenerarMovimiento(ref a, ref b);
                if (a==0)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    GenerarPiso();
                    a = 60;
                }
            }
        }

        static void Tubos(ref int a, ref int b)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+1); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+2); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+3); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+4); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+5); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+6); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+7); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+8); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+9); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+10); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+11); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+12); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+13); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+14); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+15); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+16); Console.Write("████████████████████");

            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+25); Console.Write("████████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+26); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+27); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+28); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b+29); Console.Write("  ████████████████");
        }

        static void GenerarMovimiento(ref int a, ref int b)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Tubos(ref a, ref b);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
            a--;
            Tubos(ref a, ref b);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        }


        static void GenerarPiso()
        {
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            Console.SetWindowSize(61, 37);
            for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(i, 30); Console.WriteLine("═");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(i, 31); Console.WriteLine("/");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para el parpadeo, intenta cambiar el valor de

```
 Thread.Sleep(50)
```

a 1000 o más.

```
 Thread.Sleep(2000)
```

Este valor es en milisegundos, si lo dejas en 50, no verás nada.

Acerca de lo segundo. Hay miles de maneras, y la pregunta no es muy específica. Sugiero el método de prueba y error.